# Google Captcha AutoLoad

Tags: javascript, dom-events, recaptcha, captcha

I have issue regarding Google captcha auto load. Google captcha gave me source according to the `onclick` function but I'm weak in Javascript and can't modify in the autoload function. Can anyone guide me how can I change autoload function when page load captcha auto show? The important thing is that I'm using fancybox ajax option that is why I have some complications. The code mentioned:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showRecaptcha() {
        Recaptcha.create("6Lcxj-ASAAAAAJ-OV2Sw40GfzbODQNLOTKuEFPbU", 'captchadiv', {
        tabindex: 1,
        theme: "clean",
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
}     
</script>

<div id="captchadiv"></div>

<input type="button" value="Change reCAPTCHA" onclick="showRecaptcha('captcha_div');"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ajax put Recaptcha.reload() as shown in following code

```
 $.ajax({ 
         type: 'POST', 
         url: "../yourpath", 
         data: $("#signupForm").serialize(), 
         datatype: "json", 

         success: function (response) {
             alert(response.message);
             if(response.message=="Captcha invalid"){

                   Recaptcha.reload();
                             }
         }, 
         error:  function(response, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
             alert("Some problem in saving the record : " + response.message);
         }
    });
```